# Blade template loads the resources in one sub view doesn't work for other

Tags: php, view, laravel-5, laravel-blade, subviews

I am facing a pretty strange problem working with templates in Laravel. I will demonstrate it with the following example.

**css/custom.css**

```
.muted{ color:red }
```

**Layout.blade.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> HomePage </title>
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <p>Layout file</p>
      @yield('content') 
  </body>
</html>
```

**subview1.blade.php**

```
@extends('Layout')

@section('content')
   <p class="muted"> From sub view 1 </p>
@stop
```

**subview2.blade.php**

```
@extends('Layout')

@section('content')
     <p class="muted"> From subview 2 </p>
@stop
```

Actually what is happening is that for subview 2 the class muted is not applied. And console shows that it **could not load the resource i.e custom/css** when second view is loaded but works fine with subview1

Any pointers to the real issue and solution are highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Attached is the directory structure. And I am referencing it like this.

1) dashboard_layout.blade.php (Layout File)

2) dashboard_index.blade.php ( subview1 )

3) course_index.blade.php (subview2)

**dashboard_index.blade.php**

```
@extends('teacher.dashboard.dashboard_layout')
```

**course_index.blade.php**

```
@extends('teacher.dashboard.dashboard_layout')
```

[image: blade_stack_ques_ref]

Comment: Your subviews and layout are in the same directory?

Comment: Thanks Vuldo for your time. Actually, subview1 and layout are in same directory. and subview2 in other directory. but I am referencing them right.

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly where your file are located on each others?

Comment: @Vuldo I've edited the post. Please check them

Comment: The problem doesn't come from here, you are referencing the right, I think the problem come from how the css is loaded, can you show me the `href`. Since in the second subview the css won't be called from the same path

Comment: Vuldo, both the subviews share a layout and css is referenced in that shared layout.So In my opinion that won't be an issue. What do you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, It's always confusing to reference the same assets using relative paths.You have to have an eagle eye to work out.Here comes Laravel's Html providers. Use them to reference your assets in your blade files as mentioned below rather than using simple link and script tags.

```
Html::style('assets/css/custom.css') // For style sheets.
Html::script('assets/js/custom.js') // For scritps.
```

**NOTE** : assets directory mentioned above is under your public folder as per Laravels app structure.

Html & Form Providers were shipped with Laravel basic app in previous versions.But in latest versions of Laravel. They are removed from the core.So above code snippet will produce an error. You can follow the minimal steps mentioned here [laravelcollective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html) to fix the issue.

Happy Learning !